# How to call a function using the results of a query ordered

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to call a function on each of the values that fit my query ordered by date. The reason being that the (black box) function is internally aggregating values into a string and I need the aggregated values to be in the timestamp order.

The things that I have tried are below: (function returns a boolean value and does blackbox things that I do not know and cannot modify)

```sql
-- This doesn't work
SELECT
bool_and (
  function(MT.id)
)
FROM my_table MT
WHERE ...conditions...
ORDER BY MT.timestamp_value, MT.id
```

and got the error `column "mt.timestamp_value" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function`. If I remove the ORDER BY as below, it will also work:

```sql
-- This works!
SELECT
bool_and (
  function(MT.id)
)
FROM my_table MT
WHERE ...conditions...
```

I also tried removing the `function` and only selected MT.id and it worked, but with the function it doesn't. So I tried using the GROUP BY clause. 
Doing that, I tried:

```sql
-- This also doesn't work
SELECT
bool_and(
  function(MT.id)
)
FROM my_table MT
WHERE ...conditions...
GROUP BY MT.id, MT.timestamp_value
ORDER BY MT.timestamp_value, MT.id
```

but this gives the error `more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression`. MT.id is the primary key btw. It also works without the function and just `SELECT MT.id`

Ideally, a fix to either one of the code bits above would be nice or otherwise something that fulfills the following:

```sql
-- Not real postgresql code but something I want it to do
SELECT FUNCTION(id)
FOR EACH id in (MY SELECT STATEMENT HERE ORDERED)
```

---

In response to @a_horse_with_no_name
This code falls under a section of another query that looks like the below:

```sql
SELECT Function2()
WHERE true = (
(my_snippet)
AND (...)
AND (...)
...
)
```

Comment: Is that fragment part of a bigger query? If yes, please show us the complete query (**[edit]** your question, do not post code in comments). It's unclear to me what result are you trying to get? Could you please **[edit]** your question and add some [sample data](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) and the expected output based on that data (as [formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)).

Comment: `bool_and` is an aggregate function so you need to use it together with some kind of `group by` expression. Are you maybe looking for `select bool_and(function(id)) from ...`?

Comment: I messed up writing the code. Hold on, it does look like what you said.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, I have added a very simplified version of the full query. The entire goal of the query is that it will return a single true value.

Comment: You say that: "**return value of the function is aggregated into a string**" - however how and where is that supposed to be done? By you, or in the blackbox? The return value of the **function** that is used in a "**bool_and( function(...) )**" expression can only be **true** or **false**, since the purpose of the bool_and is to return true if all returns are true, or false otherwise - can you share the exact original requirement for the purpose of this code?

Comment: The blackbox function does that for me automatically, depending on the order that the parameters are sent to it, hence the need for the ORDER BY. I solved the issue but thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

The error is clear.  The subquery `SELECT function(MT.id)` is returning more than 1 row and the calling function `bool_and` can only operate on 1 row at a time.  Adjust the subquery so that it only returns 1 record.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarity in my question. The statement works if the order by clause is not there. I have edited the question to reflect this.

Comment: ..and the group by?

Comment: The statement works when both the order by and group by are missing. Why would introducing the group by cause multiple rows to return all of a sudden?

Comment: Are you grouping by fields that you are not selecting?  ```group by``` can produce strange results if the wrong fields are included.  I would review the fields involved.

Comment: Yes, I am grouping by date even though the only field I am selecting is id. I do have date in my where conditions if that will affect anything.

Answer (score 0):

Since I have to guess the reason, and the way that you are trying to accomplish your stated goal:

> "return value of the **function** is aggregated into a string"

And since:

- You are using: **bool_and** and therefore the return value of the **function** must be **boolean**, and
- The only aggregation I can see is the **bool_and** aggregation into either **true** or **false**, and
- You mention that the **function** is a **black box** to you,

I would presume that instead of:

> "return value of the **function** is aggregated into a string"

- You meant to say: **function is aggregating (input/transformed input) values into a string**,
- And you need this aggregating to be in a certain order.
- Further I assume that you own the **my_table** and can create indexes on it.

---

So, if you need the **function** being used in the context:

> bool_and (   function(MT.id) )

to process (and therefore aggregate into string) MT.id inputs (or their transformed values) in a certain order, you need to create a clustered index in that order for your **my_table** table.

---

To accomplish that in postgresql, you need to (instead of using the **group by** and **order by**):

- create that_index, in the order you need for the aggregation, for your **my_table** table, and then
- run: `CLUSTER my_table USING that_index` to physically bake in that order to table structure, and therefore ensure the default aggregation order to be in that order in the **bool_and ( function(MT.id) )** aggregation.

(see [CLUSTER](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/sql-cluster.html) for more info)

Comment: "*and therefore ensure the default aggregation order*" - no it does not. Without an `order by` no order is guaranteed.

Comment: Theoretically, you are right, (the standard and/or documentation may support your claim,) however, every system has to have an order, even if just a random one (heap). In case of a cluster, the traversal of the data tree would be in the cluster order, in real life. Just try it out, and you would see. The documentation, and/or standard, does not prevent the easiest implementation, it just "does not guarantee it", like you said, (and/or does not mandate it).

Comment: A `group by` will change that "order", a `distinct` will change that "order", a `join` will change that "order", a parallel seq scan will change that "order", a bitmap heap scan will change that "order", a synchronized seq scans will change that "order", a parallel aggregate will change that "order"

Comment: I was talking about a solution without a group by or order by - sorry if that was not obvious.

Answer (score 0):

### Issue resolution:

I discovered the reason that everything was failing was because of the `AND` in

```
WHERE true = (
(my_snippet)
AND (...)
AND (...)
...
)
```

What happened was that using `GROUP BY` and using `ORDER BY` caused the value returned by my snippet to be multiple rows of true.

Without the `GROUP BY` and the `ORDER BY`, it only returned a single row of true.

So my solution was to wrap the code into another bool_and and use that.

```
SELECT
bool_and(vals)
FROM(
  SELECT
  bool_and(
    function(MT.id)
  ) as vals
  FROM my_table MT
  WHERE ...conditions...
  GROUP BY MT.id, MT.timestamp_value
  ORDER BY MT.timestamp_value, MT.id
) t
```

Comment: The order in which the boolean values are fed into `bool_and()` is completely meaningless because `false and false and true`  will yield the same result as `false and true and false` (which is what `bool_and()` will do)

Comment: Yes. The ordering is only needed for calls to `function` itself. The order that the parameters are read into function needs to be ordered by date. However, the overlying wrapper requires a single row and so this will resolve it. I do not know if it is optimal though.

Comment: And this is going to be a mighty expensive solution on a large data set. If you care, and there is no insert time or other restriction not mentioned here, try to get rid of all the extra bool_and, group by, order by, sub-query, and try my simple index solution. It should be orders of magnitude faster on large data sets.

Comment: @LuciferMorningstar, I know for certain that my WHERE conditions will return at most 10,000 values. Will using indexing still speed it up significantly?

Comment: Yes, that is a good case for indexing, few hundred, or few thousand usually may be practically insignificant, the 10000 would surely show. Plus, the extra work you are doing instead, (group by, order by, extra bool_and, subquery) really is expensive, so you may see improvements in speed anywhere from 1000 to 1000000 times range in my opinion.